# Can't understand what this lw is doing

Tags: mips

I have to find which is the mips code of that C instruction:
B[8] = A[i-j]
The variables i, j are in the registers $s3, $s4, while the base address of A and B are $s6,$s7

When I read the solutions I can't understand why in the lw instruction(third line of code) I have to specify the offset.
Didn't I calculate it in the second line?

Thank you and sorry for any English mistakes.

```
sub $t0,$s3,$s4
add $t0,$s6,$t0
lw  $t1,16($t0)
sw $t1,32($s7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're calculating here is the **byte** offset:

```
sub $t0,$s3,$s4
```

If we assume that the elements in your arrays are words (4 bytes) - since you're using `lw` and `sw` - then you need to scale that offset accordingly:

```
sll $t0, $t0, 2    # $t0 *= 4
```